# Replace parent table keeping child tables

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have searched for this on SO but none of the options seems to work as intended. I have a table that has content I want to reformat, but ocasionally it can come with inner tables I do want to keep as tables. The problem is that I want to delete the parent table but leaving possible inner tables. Here is my code.

```
var crespformat = $('#contenido-resp');
var crespcontent = crespformat.find("td, th").contents().detach();
crespformat.find("table").remove();
crespformat.append(crespcontent);
```

I tried using selectors to get the first level child like `.find('.contentpanel > td, .contentpanel > th')` or `children('table')`, but it doesn't work. The first table has a *contentpanel* class, but doesn't help me so much.

EDIT:

Here is the HTML I want to reformat

```
<div id="contenido-resp">
<table class="contentpanel">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
           <td>
               <img src="http://www.domain..." alt="..." />
           <p>
               Some content here
           </p>
           <table>
                 <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                          <p><!-- Content I do want to remain as table --></p>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                          <span><!-- Content I do want to remain as table --></span>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                          <!-- Content I do want to remain as table -->
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And my desired HTML output would be this:

```
<div id="contenido-resp">
   <img src="http://www.domain..." alt="..." />
       <p>
           Some content here
       </p>
       <table>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <p><!-- Content I do want to remain as table --></p>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <span><!-- Content I do want to remain as table --></span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <!-- Content I do want to remain as table -->
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
</div>
```

But with my current code I get this

```
<div id="contenido-resp">
   <img src="http://www.domain..." alt="..." />
       <p>
           Some content here
       </p>
       <p><!-- Content I do want to remain as table --></p>
       <span><!-- Content I do want to remain as table --></span>
       <!-- Content I do want to remain as table -->
</div>
```

Here I link the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2of0kLp7/embedded/result/

Comment: Please show enough, or a simplified example, of your starting HTML and the expected output of the jQuery that we might compose in order to help you out. Describing your problem isn't as effective as *showing* us your problem. Also, leaving out the relevant code renders your question [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for the site, and I'd rather not have a potentially useful question closed if it could be avoided. For guidance please see "[ask]" and "[MCVE]" guidelines.

Comment: A jsfiddle with the HTML tables and your code would be quite helpful to anyone trying to help you with this...

Comment: Added a JSFiddle and code reference in case JSFiddle fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.clone()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var crespformat = $('#contenido-resp');  
  var crespcontent = crespformat.find("td:first");
  var content = crespcontent.find("img, p, table").clone();
  crespformat.html(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="contenido-resp">
  <table class="contentpanel">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" alt="..." />
          <p>
            Some content here
          </p>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>Text on first celll</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span>Content on second cell</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="img-on-cell" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2of0kLp7/3/

Comment: Hi guest, well unfortunately it seems this code snippet doesn't work on jsfiddle, but I'm trying to work on it on my development code. I should edit your answer if I can figure it out. Clone() is a nice approach though

Comment: @JonathanXXI _"it seems this code snippet doesn't work on jsfiddle"_ ?Appear to return same results at stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2of0kLp7/2/ , here

Comment: but it doesn't keep child tables, that's my intended purpose, why is it different from my current code?

Comment: well it know works :D it was odd previous times I executed it simply showed the same result I already had, I'll implement it, thank you :)